# WCF 4 on IIS 6: using asynchronous request handlers?

Tags: wcf

Does WCF 4 use an asynchronous HTTP Module/Handler when hosted in IIS6?

The question has been answered for 3.5 and IIS6/7:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2008/08/13/orcas-sp1-improvement-asynchronous-wcf-http-module-handler-for-iis7-for-better-server-scalability.aspx

But I cannot find an answer for WCF 4 on IIS 6.

If no, how can an application be configured to use the async implementation?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work like a charm.

Even though I couldn't find any official piece of MS documentation about it.

Adding the following HTTP handlers/modules does the trick.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.svc" />
  <add path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>
</httpHandlers>

<httpModules>   
  <remove name="ServiceModel" />
  <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</httpModules>
```